# Coloring cells in HTML table creates new cells

Tags: html, pandas, dataframe, background-color

I am comparing values in a dataframe from pandas, and want to color them based on the comparison. To do this, I am doing this:

```
if event_time_seconds <= cut_seconds:
    styled_df.loc[index, column] = 'style="background-color: green">{}'.format(styled_df.loc[index, column])
else:
    styled_df.loc[index, column] = 'style="background-color: red">{}'.format(styled_df.loc[index, column])
```

However, that creates a new empty cell in Its place and colors the one to the left of it.

Here you can see that the data has been moved from the 'SM B' and 'SM A' columns, and new cells have been created.
[Table where the data has been moved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTCy4.png)

I have also tried doing this, without the , but that just turns into text and doesn't change the color of the cells:

```
if event_time_seconds <= cut_seconds:
    styled_df.loc[index, column] = '<td style="background-color: green">{}.         </td>'.format(styled_df.loc[index, column])
else:
    styled_df.loc[index, column] = '<td style="background-color: red">{}     </td>'.format(styled_df.loc[index, column])
```

When I inspect the HTML table using dev tools in the browser, I can see that there are empty cells in the HTML code, but when I print the HTML code to the terminal, there is no trace of the empty cells. What is the solution?